# R: How to convert double to raw and back?

Tags: r

There a `as.raw` function and `intToBits` function.

So I can convert a `double` to bits but how do I convert it back to `double`.

The use case is convert `double` to `raw` so I can compress with `fst::compress_fst`, then write it to disk using `writeBin`, then read it back. But because I can't find a way to convert `raw` back to `double`, this seems impossible at the moment.

To convert `integer` to raw and back, is `packBits(intToBits(1:10), type = "integer")`. What's the equivalent for double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is close, but there's no need to make a file for this.

```
doubleToRaw <- function(d) { writeBin(d, raw()); }
rawToDouble <- function(r) { readBin(r, numeric()); }
```

Example:

```
> rr = doubleToRaw(pi)
# [1] 18 2d 44 54 fb 21 09 40
> rawToDouble(rr)
# [1] 3.141593
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
bin_data <- file("testbin", "rb")
readBin(bin_Data, numeric(), size=8)
```

[There are some examples of doing this on the bottom of this page](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/readBin.html)

Comment: would accept as answer if thee relevant codes are copied here for easy reference for others

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).